# Размещение рекламы AdSense на сайте

Tags: html, google-adsense

Как разместить рекламу на сайте, написанном на PHP?

[Тестовый сайт, но не работает](http://izdeme.kz/abzal/asd.php).

Код AdSense:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- izdeme.kz -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-12122508483470146"
        data-ad-slot="3000096519">
</ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Судя по всему, AdSense вам просто не отдает рекламу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код AdSense на тестовом сайте вроде размещён верно.

Кстати, а давно был создан аккаунт в AdSense? Если недавно, то придётся подождать пока сайт пройдёт модерацию. В период модерации реклама показываться не будет.
Если сайт не прошёл модерацию, остаётся только переписываться с модераторами AdSense.

Comment: Да аккаунт был создан давно!

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что нужно сделать - это отключить любые расширения, блокирующие рекламу :)

Если Вы рекламу нигде больше не размещали (нигде, кроме этой тестовой странички), то и модерацию Вы не пройдете. Именно поэтому, скорее всего, у Вас не показывается реклама.

Решение: Пройдите модерацию, разместив рекламу на реальном сайте (где Вы планируете и далее показывать рекламу)

Также желательно хорошо ознакомиться с правилами по размещению рекламы: [Правила AdSense: руководство для начинающих](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/23921?hl=ru)